# s3 how is the signature calculated

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having trouble trying to figure out what is required for the signature. I see some examples using hex, and others I see using base64. Which one is it?

`Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', getSignatureKey,  @policy)).gsub(/\n|\r/, '')`

Or:

`OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), getSignatureKey, @policy).gsub(/\n|\r/, '')`

Comment: It depends on which Signature Bersion you are using.  Common versions are V2 (base64) and V4 (hex).  Please link to a document for what  you're trying to implement and perhaps we can clarify this.

Comment: Ahh okay i'm doing v4 with a post to s3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I got it. There are two very important things to consider when creating the signature. A) how the signature is calculated, and B) how your bucket policy is set up. I'm assuming that your CORS are configured to allow a post, and that your IAM user/group has s3 access; and really should only have s3 access.

The bucket policy for the form data requires:
`["starts-with", "$key", "{{intended_file_path}}"]`,
`"x-amz-credential"`,
`"x-amz-algorithm"`,
`"x-amz-date"`,
`"bucket"`

The `["starts-with", "$key"` should be the intended file destination path - ie, "uploads", or "user/jack/", or "images", whatever - see example below.

Here is how I signed my signatures, as well as my bucket policy.

Bucket Config:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow Get",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-development/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/example"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::example-development/*","arn:aws:s3:::example-development"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Backend:

```
def string_to_sign

    @time = Time.now.utc
    @time_policy = @time.strftime('%Y%m%dT000000Z')
    @date_stamp = @time.strftime('%Y%m%d')

     ret = {"expiration" => 10.hours.from_now.utc.iso8601,
            "conditions" =>  [
                {"bucket" => ENV["aws_bucket"]},
                {"x-amz-credential": "#{ENV["aws_access_key"]}/#{@date_stamp}/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request"},
                {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
                { "acl": "public-read" },
                {"x-amz-date": @time_policy },
                ["starts-with", "$key", "uploads"], 
            ]
            }
    @policy = Base64.encode64(ret.to_json).gsub(/\n|\r/, '')

end

def getSignatureKey
        kDate = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', ("AWS4" +  ENV["aws_secret_key"]), @date_stamp)
        kRegion = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kDate, 'us-west-2')
        kService = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kRegion, 's3')
        kSigning = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kService, "aws4_request")
    end

def sig
        sig = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), getSignatureKey, @policy).gsub(/\n|\r/, '')
end
```