# s3 minimum upload bucket policy authorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get a basic upload bucket to work, but I'm having trouble trying to wrap my head around the bucket policy needed.

I currently have:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::waydope-development/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "public-read"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The CORS are set to allow all. I can upload to this bucket by only supplying a key, but will this bucket if supplied with authorization, signature, and policy, return a 403 due to the fact that it is open? In other words, can I supply those keys without having the principal point at a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see how a bucket policy relates to signing here is a question related to that: [s3 how is the signature calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618038/s3-how-is-the-signature-calculated/42637820?noredirect=1#comment72414550_42637820)

This is the minimum bucket policy where anyone can get, post, put, and delete an item in a bucket. All that is required in the formdata is the key - ie, file path.

Bucket Config:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*"
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-development/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the minimum bucket policy where user/group authentication is required for anything besides get for the bucket upload.

Bucket Config:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow Get",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-development/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/example"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::example-development/*","arn:aws:s3:::example-development"]
        }
    ]
}
```